# Launch screen auto layout issues

Tags: ios, xcode

When I try to set auto layout controls for a UIImageView from the storyboard object library on my launch screen xib, ie clicking `pin` or `arrange`, my image doesn't move to place & no issues show up in the viewcontroller scene like they do when I set constraints on a viewcontroller in the storyboard. Why? And how can I set auto layout controls for a UIImageView on a xib if there is no viewcontroller scene to help me fix auto layout issues? thanks

Comment: Do you know about control-dragging to create constraints?

Comment: Do you understand the four buttons at the bottom right? How about the Editor menu, with Resolve Auto Layout Issues?

Comment: yes, the problem is that when I do, no issues are revealed to solve so my image doesn't move

Comment: Do you see the document outline at the left? If you don't, do you know how to show it? If you don't see a little yellow or red arrow in the document outline, there are no issues. If you do, click it.

Comment: i didn't know about the editor menu thanks.

Comment: i think i got it now thank you. noob mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a *xib* file, auto layout issues appear in the document outline, just as in a storyboard. If you don't see a little yellow or red arrow in the document outline, there are no issues. If you do, click it:

[image]

[image]